# A specific word for not caring about an issue until you're personally affected or victimized by it

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Suppose you read about suicides. The first few reads are dolorous, but over time, you become desensitized. You forget after minutes about a story that would've destroyed you five months ago. However, along comes news of a suicide in your own family, and suddenly, you campaign for suicide prevention, and dedicate every waking hour to that cause.

To take another example, consider reading about muggings, thefts, and burglaries in your area—you learn it's a hot spot, and although it's sad your neighbours were victimized, your concern eventually wanes. You cease to think about their actual, and even your potential, victimization. After you get mugged, have your car stolen, and your house burgled, you suddenly care more, become hyper-aware of it.

The concept I'm trying to capture is indifference/apathy-turned-ardency after being personally affected or victimized by what you were previously indifferent/apathetic towards. Many adjectives/nouns fit my description—self-obsessed, self-centered, apathetic, narcissistic, narcissist, egomaniac, etc.—but they're non-specific. I'm looking for a word or phrase with a more precise definition.

Example sentences:

____ refers to the phenomenon where one begins to care for a cause only after being affected by it on a personal level.

It's extremely ____ of him to change his view on climate change only after a flood swallowed his precious little hut.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't have a sample sentence in mind, but it's unclear to me a sample sentence would help. If others insist, I'll think one up, but I'm just looking to capture this concept with a word. The part of speech doesn't matter to me. Perhaps my request is a tall order, but I've stumbled upon rare and literary words with very precise definitions, so I ask on the off-chance one exists for this.

Comment: You've become sensitised to the issue, but 'overly sensitised' probably fits better. ['You' as in your first sentence.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sensitised and sensitisation are good words but lack the specificity of having occurred as a result of being personally affected by the thing you're becoming sensitised to.

Comment: How can you become sensitised in without there being a specific stimulus? 'Sensitive' does not mandate there being an overt causative agent, but 'sensitise' certainly does. It's a verb necessitating transformation brought about by an agent (an allergen, a traumatic experience ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not a question of whether there's an overt causative agent, but what that overt causative agent is. I may watch gore, become desensitised, go a period without watching it, and become sensitised upon re-watching. Important here is that something happens either to you directly, as in you get mugged, or to a friend or family member, per my examples. I realise you can be affected by strangers, but the idea is you become sensitised because the stimulus affects you in a more self-interested way.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/485528/191178

Comment: The niggling is the reason that I left this place.

Comment: @G.Rem On whose end?

Comment: @KannE I omitted FITB sentences to increase room for maneuver, but since they're mandatory, I added a couple to my original post.

Comment: @user438484  I voted for you.  I saw the maneuvering a mile away.  It's like one guy loads the question, and, then, the next one tees off on it.

Comment: @G.Rem What does it mean to vote for me? I'm new to this website.

Comment: @user438484 I up-voted your question.  So did someone else.  If I recall, more points are required to down vote things.  In jest, I guess that once you have a million points, you sublimate into God.  Don't hold your breath, though.  Seriously, do it for fun, but, not the points.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a single word/adjective that captures *both* the before and after attitudes you describe. You mention that a phrase is also acceptable. I would focus on the transformative/victimizing event itself.

> After you get mugged, have your car stolen, and your house burgled,
> you suddenly **care more, become hyper-aware of it**.

Such an event **hits home** and the person understands it in a new light.

**hit home** (idiom)

> To become very clear and obvious in usually a **forceful or unpleasant
> way**
>
> *The truth about their marriage finally hit home.* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit%20home)

> To be especially memorable, meaningful, or significant; to be fully
> understood, believed or appreciated. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_home)

> If a situation or what someone says **hits home** or **strikes home**,
> people realize that it is real or true, **even though it may be painful
> for them to accept it.**
>
> *In many cases the reality of war doesn't hit home with reservists until they're actually called upon to fight.* Collins [ref](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hit-home)

---

> To be persuaded to take action, readers must become involved with the
> issue: it must **hit home**. You should decide how to appeal to the
> audience emotionally, by picking a part of a situation that can make
> them "live" the experience.
> ... One devastating traffic accident can show the need for stricter
> drunk-driving laws.  [K. Adams and J. Adams; *The Accomplished
> Writer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Accomplished_Writer/Z3LWAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=one%20devastating%20traffic)

> The dangers of highway robbery **hit home** for Butler after an
> incident in which the gang attempted to hold up a coach on 27 April
> 1723.  [Fiona McDonald; *Gentlemen Rogues & Wicked Ladies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mNESDQAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT82&dq=after%20the%20burglary%20hit%20home&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=after%20the%20burglary%20hit%20home&f=false)

> The mugging **hit close to home** for Father Roy. [Charles Thompson;
> *Border Odyssey*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JDOyBwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA97&dq=after%20the%20mugging%20hit%20home&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=after%20the%20mugging%20hit%20home&f=false)

> I believe that when you are actually reading all of this it will all
> **hit home** and **make you angry enough** to demand the very much needed change that we are all deserving of, and **you will be complacent no
> more**. [Alicia Rolow; *The Plane Truth from an American Airlines
> Flight Attendant*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Plane_Truth_from_an_American_Airline/2v3G4QgjIZ4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hit%20home%22%20no%20longer%20complacent&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcover)

> Once again, we see how emotional upheavals enable significant
> realizations to “**hit home**” with us. [Rick Furtak; *Knowing
> Emotions*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knowing_Emotions/3u5IDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hit%20home%22%20emotionally&pg=PA155&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

Complacent.

The definition of complacent is happy with one's self and unconcerned. An example of complacent is a person working in their office and not worried about the dangerous weather conditions outside.